# Spring Boot Actuator: management.endpoints vs management.endpoint?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a project using Spring Boot `2.7.3` with this in the `application.yml`:

```yaml
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include:
          health,info,metrics,prometheus
  endpoint:
    health:
      probes:
        enabled: true
```

Why is there a `management.endpoints` when there is a `management.endpoint` ? Why not merge all properties into one?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, `management.endpoints` (plural) properties configure *how* and *where* actuator endpoints are exposed. These have more to do with configuring actuator as a whole, and inform the way it will integrate with your application and tools. For example:

- `management.endpoints.jmx.exposure.*` - what endpoints are exposed via JMX?
- `management.endpoints.jmx.domain` - what domain should be used to name MBeans?
- `management.endpoints.web.exposure.*` - what endpoints are exposed over the web?
- `management.endpoints.web.base-path` - under what base path should web endpoints be served?
- `management.endpoints.enabled-by-default` - should all endpoints be *enabled* by default? (note that *enabled* and *exposed* are separate concerns)

The `management.endpoint` (singular) properties apply to *individual* actuator endpoints, allowing each endpoint to define its own configurable properties. Specific configurations live under `management.endpoint.<endpointId>.*`. Hence, it is effectively a namespace reserved for unique and identifiable endpoints. For example:

- `management.endpoint.health.show-details` - should detailed health info be shown?
- `management.endpoint.health.roles` - what user roles are permitted to see detailed health info?
- `management.endpoint.env.enabled` - should env endpoint be *enabled*? (note that instrumentation is skipped entirely for disabled endpoints)
- `management.endpoint.env.additional-keys-to-sanitize` - what additional patterns should be used to sanitize sensitive env vars?

---

TL;DR:

- `management.endpoints.*` globally configures common endpoint properties and the ways in which endpoints may be accessed.
- `management.endpoint.<endpointId>.*` individually configures the endpoint identified by `endpointId`, which may define its own unique configurable properties.